# How to compute dBm from FFT results?

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, decibel

I computed a sinewave of 4Hz, applied FFT and calculated the amplitude, the amplitude is an array of 500 length, I want to convert each element in that array to dBm form, and draw a spectrogram. however I can't seem to get the calculation right.

I saw that general formula:

*valueDBFS = 20*np.log10(abs(value))

so I tried using it and I get only negative results..

Here is my full code (edited):

```
# Python example - Fourier transform using numpy.fft method
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plotter
from os import times
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# How many time points are needed i,e., Sampling Frequency
samplingFrequency = 100
# At what intervals time points are sampled
samplingInterval = 1 / samplingFrequency
# Begin time perod of the signals
beginTime = 0
# End time period of the signals
endTime = 10
# Frequency of the signals
signal1Frequency = 4
signal2Frequency = 70

# Time points
time = np.arange(beginTime, endTime, samplingInterval)
# Create two sine waves
amplitude1 = 100 * np.sin(2*np.pi*signal1Frequency*time)

fourierTransform = np.fft.fft(amplitude1)
fourierTransform = fourierTransform[range(int(len(amplitude1)/2))] # Exclude sampling frequency
tpCount = len(amplitude1)
values = np.arange(int(tpCount/2))
timePeriod = tpCount/samplingFrequency
frequencies = values/timePeriod


valueDBFS = 20*np.log10(abs(fourierTransform))

print(valueDBFS)

#SPECTROGRAM
w, h = 500, 500
data = np.zeros((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
time = time[:len(time)//2]
for i in range(500):
    for j in range(500):
        color = abs(fourierTransform)[i]
        data[i,j] = [color, color, color] 
        
img = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')
img.show()
```

Comment: For dBm your system would need to be calibrated so that you know the signal level which corresponds to 1 mW. For dBFS though this doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value of your amplitude is 1, and log10(1) is 0, everything else will be less than that - for example log10(0.9) = -0,0458.

So that part of your code works fine, the logs should be negative in your example! - Try defining your amplitude like this:

```
amplitude1 = 100 * np.sin(2*np.pi*signal1Frequency*time)
```

That should give plenty of positive results.

Comment: What does the 100 stands for? like if I write 0.5 vs 100

Comment: @yarinCohen np.sin() returns values in [-1, 1] range, this multiplies every value by 100 and makes it [-100, 100] range. Also, i've missed that you were asking for dBm, it is also important what your sine wave is representing, dBm is usually defined as 10*log10(P/1mW) where mW is a milliwatt.

Comment: I tried your code and it did do something, my results are mostly ~30 now but I also have some values there around -250 what is that?

Comment: also, there's an inf value in there so something's up

Comment: @yarinCohen Yes, there should still be some values that are negative and -inf, thats cause there are zeros and small values in your sine wave, you probably want to convert the frequency response (the fft) to dBm. So use abs(fourierTransform) instead of abs(amplitude1)

Comment: I edited the code like you said, can you please verify that I did everything ok, since I'm getting -200 results again.

Comment: @yarinCohen A true sine wave of 4Hz would only have kronecker delta on -4Hz and +4Hz. So for all other frequencies aside from those 2 fft should be 0 - which means -inf in dB. Since we are working with discrete data, this wont be the case for you, but the values should approach 0. On the peaks, the values should be 20*log10(100)

Comment: I went over the value DBFS array, and the highest value is 307 for some reason not 0